# Python - 2D Array, Input in Array

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to Python, started studying 2 weeks ago, now i need to make one thing and i am totally stuck.

My task is :

Write an algorithm which will have the following requirements:

1) Array A[n][m] will be read from keyboard, maxn=10, maxm=10

2) Find a sum of negative elements for every row below row 7 in array A (one sum per every row) and output them on the screen

First of all, i don't understand, A[n][m] - maybe it should be 2D array, but from other languages i know that 2D is something like A[[]].
Coming out of this i don't understand maxn = 10 and maxm = 10.

Anybody? Any help? Any codes?

Comment: I don't think we are allowed to encourage questions that ask for an entire code. Please get some rough sketch and we can help you debug that!

Comment: It is a 2 dimension array with parameters n and m. After that, you should post the code you have written so far

Comment: `A[n][m]` is indeed indexing for a 2D array, at least in Python.

Answer (score -1):

I won't post the code, but i will tell you how you should look your problem
You need to create 2 variables that store the dimensions of the array.
Then you have to create a double for loop that reads values from the keyboard and assigns it to the array.

Check [input() method](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html)

Then by using the same loop but starting from row 7 you find the sum you need and you print it.